# Can't send email to some servers

Tags: email, email-server, reverse-dns

I get this error below, after I send email to some domains including charter.net

```
SMTP error from remote mail server after MAIL FROM:<******@mydomain.com>:
550 5.7.1 Connections not accepted from servers without a valid sender domain.alph736 Fix reverse DNS for 45.76.12.x
```

I have a reverse DNS record, I can send email successfully to almost every other domain including gmail, hotmail. My emails are not SPAM. How to solve the issue?

Comment: Which HELO (or EHLO) string does you server send? (This is the first thing server sends after connecting to other server and receiving its banner.) While it is not required by RFC, some servers do various checks with hostname presented in that string. I suspect you have exactly `domain.alph736` in it. In general, it is recommended to set that to server's public fully-qualified domain name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reverse DNS does not have a valid hostname.

https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=smtp%3a45.76.12.187&run=toolpage

Comment: is vovsoft.com not a valid hostname?

Comment: Nope, it's a domain name. I tried again and I see you corrected in  mail.vovsoft.com , now it should work fine.